# Android GPS. read location every second and write to array(s) and file

Tags: android, gps

Android GPS. My first question.

I've been reading for weeks and made some progress but now I'm stumped. I've written a program that writes to the screen on location changed but what I want to do is get latitude longitude altitude and time regularly, say every half second, and regardless of location change and write them to an array and a text file. I know it sounds weird I have my reasons.

I understand the battery and performance issues.

I haven't done any programming for 15 years, I've never been much good in high level environments and I'm struggling.

Also if I manipulate the values as doubles how much precision do I lose. I know about the GPS accuracy but I still want to maintain precision.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: can you let me know the use case. within half a second, there will be no significant change in a user's position. You can check Google fused location API. you can receive location update from the device as mentioned in the tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: `My first question`. There is no question.

Comment: I'm doing an experiment to see how accurate I can get the distance and bearing between 2 phones using differential gps within say 500 metres of each other. I want to build an array of readings and compare them. After I posted this question I thought further on one of the comments I'd read elsewhere so now I'm thinking it might be easier to accumulate a lot of data off onLocationChanged, maybe 100 readings, and use the time stamp intervals in my smoothing. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I've read that tutorial page many times but frankly I find the other blogs on the web easier to follow than google's own documentation. Nevertheless I will read it over again. Thank you.